# transient attribute in Factory Bot not working

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, transient

I have this object that contains a word where the default value is 101.

```
 trait :word do
      transient do
        width 101
      end

      after(:create) do |object, evaluator|
        word_x = "x" * evaluator.width
        object.word = word_x
      end
    end
```

I call

```
create :object :word, width: 800
```

and it's perfect the object.word has a word of length 800 in the ruby test file.

However the class I'm testing shows that object.word has a word of length 101. 
It's like it forgets that I set it.

What's going on?
.

EDIT: in my class, i query for objects using SQL. Would that be affecting the object?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code from the class that you're testing?  It would seem that the answer lies in that code, but we cannot see it.

Comment: @anu can you double check that you are in fact setting the width for the object that you are testing? Perhaps you've mistakenly set it for another object?

Comment: if you query for objects using SQL how does it use the factory? Can you please give more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `after(:create)` function changes the object, but does not save the change. If you then query for that object from the database, it will not have the change.

```
obj = create(:object, :word, width: 800)
p obj.word # 800 long
p obj.changed? # true

# Re-fetch it from the database.
obj.reload
p obj.word # 101 long
```

It's more robust to do this as part of the `word` attribute.

```
factory :object do
  transient do
    word_width { 11 }
  end

  word { "x" * word_width }
end
```